# Please adopt containerBackground API

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos, widgetkit

After updating to the Xcode beta and build/running my app, I started to get an error on all my widgets "Please adopt containerBackground API" and I found a post that had a solution to accommodate iOS 14-16

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func widgetBackground() -> some View {
        let gradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("LightBlue"), Color("DarkBlue")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
        
        if #available(watchOS 10.0, iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, iOS 17.0, macOSApplicationExtension 14.0, *) {
            self.containerBackground(gradient, for: .widget)
        } else {
            self.background(gradient)
        }
    }
}
```

I add this to my ZStack for the widget and it does nothing. I still get the same error to adopt to containerBackground API. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure that this code is the issue. This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Getting the same error here. And I building against watchOS 10 as the start. We will figure this out...

Comment: In SwiftUI Preview, switch *Widget Context* to "Smart Stack Rectangular", are you able to see your background? Try `Color.blue.gradient` as an experiment instead of your own custom gradient.

Comment: It is possible that you, like me, tried to run the widget extension target on your Apple Watch hardware. Running the app target, and now I can see the widget with a background.

Comment: [rdar://FB13141297](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5575113021849600)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add .containerBackground(.....) to all of your widget views whether or not they previously had .background or not